# Is there any point to use a form element client side?

Tags: javascript, html

In a client side app where the submitting of the form happens via ajax, would there be any point in using the html form element? 
Since I need to do `e.preventDefault()` every time just to make sure that the form does not submit, but rather the info gets sent through ajax, I would consider it pointless to use the form element. Am I missing something? I ask because I remember seeing the form used in the tutorials  I watched to learn react and vue.

Comment: It's handy for grouping input elements etc and for some APIs.

Comment: Grouping, easier access through document.forms, automatic serialization of all the fields inside the form, easier support for disabled people, etc. But yes, I stopped using forms as well unless I have need for those form builtins.

Comment: @ScottMarcus — non-standard? `document.forms` appears [here, in the Document Object Model (DOM) Level 2 HTML Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-1689064) from the W3C.

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: `FormData` requires forms, and is very useful for handling form data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for many reasons.

Form elements group form controls. This is particularly useful for people using assistive technology (such as screen readers), some of which have dedicated form input modes.

Having a real form allows you to use [progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) (a fundemental requirement of [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)), which makes you site robuster and able to withstand [a client failing to run the JavaScript](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html).

Sending data by Ajax requires that you collect all the data with JavaScript. This can be done conveniently by instantiating a [`FormData` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) with the form object.

```
var data = new FormData(document.forms.formid);
myXhr.send(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Semantics; http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

> A semantic element clearly describes its meaning to both the browser
>   and the developer.

Will allow things like autocomplete to work correctly in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

For one, it has semantic meaning. Secondly, it allows shortcuts to extracting data from form elements:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
formData = new FormData(myForm);
```

Or shortcuts to accessing form fields:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
myForm[fieldIndex]
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you dont need to prevent form Submission, just make sure you have your form action attribute marked to #
 so that it stays on the same page.